# Return input in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and am having a hard time returning the value of an input when the table is in responsive mode:

[image: This is the table when it's in responsive mode where the screen is as small as possible.]

Here is my table:

```
  <table id="productsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Code</th>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price ($)</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each context}}
        <tr>
            <td class="product_code">{{product_code}}</td>
            <td class="supplier">{{supplier}}</td>
            <td class="category">{{category}}</td>
            <td class="description">{{description}}</td>
            <td class="price">{{invoice_price}}</td>
            <td class="quantity"><input type="number" class="{{product_code}}"></td>
            <td><a class="details" href="/product/{{product_code}}">Details</a></td>
            <td><button id="{{product_code}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</button></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I assigned a unique product code to the class of each input and tried to return the value with:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() { 
    var product_code = this.id; //product_code is defined by the Add to Cart's button ID
    //var quantity = $("." + product_code).val();
    var quantity = $("#productsTable input[name='"+ product_code+"'").val();
    console.log(quantity);

});
```

That works if table is at full size but returns undefined when the table is shrunk.. can someone help? I might need a special function for returning dynamically created inputs, but I'm not sure how to do that either...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `product_code` ?

Comment: in the table, it's generated using my handlebars template. it's a unique identifier for each product in the row

Comment: but in ur js it's a variable you know that right ?

Comment: Yes, and it works if the table is full-size, but not if it's shrunk

Comment: can you post `var product_code = ...........` ?

Comment: I just guess that there is a misch-masch in class string while shrunk. Could you try different selector. E.g. `<input type="number" name="{{product_code}}"> ` and jQuery `var quantity = $("#productsTable td[name='"+  product_code+"'").val();`

Comment: can you post your full code ?

Comment: hmm, still getting the same issue @Daniel.P. although it does work when the table is full size..

Comment: yes, i just added the full code for my click event @John

Comment: Could you please verify that selector matches (while shrunk)?
  `var test = $("input[name='"+ product_code+"'").length;
  console.log(test);`

Comment: Try using the [responsive extension](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive) for DataTables , Responsive is an extension for DataTables that resolves that problem by optimising the table's layout for different screen sizes through the dynamic insertion and removal of columns from the table.

Answer (score 3):

You have forgot to actually give the `<input>`'s a `name`, i.e. the `input[name='"+ product_code+"'")` you are refering to. And that selector should btw be `input[name='"+ product_code+"']")`, you forget the closing bracket `]`.

Eventually your code would work when the dataTable is "not responsive" because you do a readonly lookup on visible elements. However, when dealing with dataTables it is generally a good idea to use the API, also on trivial taks. If you have a table

```js
var table = $('#productsTable').DataTable()
```

Then retrieve the internal quantity `<input>` directly from the API using `row()`, to get the current value regardless of the state of the dataTable :

```js
table.on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
  var trNode = table.row(this.parentElement.parentElement).node()
  var quantity = trNode.querySelector('input').value
  console.log(quantity)
})
```

This works assuming your markup is as described - the `<button>` is not wrapped into other elements, the `<input>` is the only one present is each row.

---

If you wonder why I am not using jQuery methods it is because the same would look like this

```
table.on('click', 'button.btn.btn-primary', function() {
  var trNode = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).node()
  var quantity =  $(trNode).find('input').val()
  console.log(quantity)
})
```

more confusing if you ask me ...